# WPF WrapPanel with tab stop?

Tags: c#, wpf, wrappanel

I'm interested into make a wrap panel (plenty of other user control) to be a tab stop. The panel is within a scroll viewer, the scroll viewer do have the IsTabStop property, but the scroll viewer doesn't. I want the user to be able to use tab key to navigate each by one of the user controls located within the wrap papel.

Answer (score 0):

Are you locking for the [Focuable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.iinputelement.focusable.aspx) property?